# What are the differences between useEffect versus componentDidMount/componentWillUnmount? What are the differences between hooks and this.setState?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

The goal of the following code is to render quotes received from an observable in a table.
I have two versions of the code, one a react function using hooks and useEffect, and the other a react class using setState and componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount. With the react function, the quotes are not displayed at all. With the react class, the table is constantly updated. If I am doing something wrong with the function, what is it? If I am using it correctly, what is the difference between hooks and useEffect that it does not work, and componentDidMount/willUnmount that it does work?

function:

```
function DisplayQuotes() {
  const [storedQuotes, setQuotes] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription = SymbolsObservable.subscribe(setQuotes);
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [storedQuotes, setQuotes]);
  return (
    <div>
      <QuotesTable values={storedQuotes} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

class:

```
class DisplayQuotes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { storedQuotes: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscription = SymbolsObservable.subscribe((quotes) =>
      this.setState({ storedQuotes: quotes })
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <QuotesTable values={this.state.storedQuotes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you approach sharing the functionality of `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount`, and `setState` with class based components to avoid duplication?

Comment: not sure what you mean, sorry somewhat new to react :) If your asking why would you do it as a class, this is why I am trying to figure out why the function wont work

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to subscribe to `SymbolsObservable` when the component is mounted, and unsubscribe to the RxJS subscription when the component is unmounted.

Therefore, the equivalent for it in react hooks would be to use an [empty dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) for the useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let subscription = SymbolsObservable.subscribe(setQuotes);
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: I will for sure take note, of this, but it is not the solution :(. still no new quotes

Comment: Actually, shouldnt i put the storedQuotes as a dependency, as this is the value that i want to compare if it is changing? Doc: If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect.